# Is there a Javascript client for Ethereum, like Geth?

Tags: clients, nodes, javascript, ethereumjs

Ethereum's Github has [ethereumjs-lib](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-lib).  It appears to be a collection of modules, but is it also a client like Geth?  If so, how can one run this Javascript client?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there are [3 official clients](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/279/87) in Golang, C++ and Python. And there are 4 unofficial clients in Java, Haskell, **JavaScript** and most recently Rust.

To answer your question, the full node client implementation in JavaScript is the [node-blockchain-server](https://github.com/ethereumjs/node-blockchain-server) of the [ethereumjs](http://ethereumjs.github.io/) project.

The node-blockchain-server aims to provide a full Ethereum node implementation. It is in a pretty rough state at the moment, but at least can download the blockchain.

In oposite to other client implementations, for JavaScript you need to add a couple of libraries to get a *fullstack* client. Check out [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum) for managing keys and [ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx) for creating transactions with them.

The full list of libraries (23) in the ethereumjs project can be found [on their homepage](http://ethereumjs.github.io/).

Comment: node-blockchain-server says "It doesn't do state transitions".  Not clear what that means.  Also, can you send it transactions?

Comment: No, updated my answer.

Comment: Looks like the answer to this is "not yet".  If/when mentioning "need to add a couple libraries", I think it would be better to describe that more ;)

Comment: Can you scan the ethereum blockchain with these?