# Ethereum Indexers

Tags: blockchain, ethereumj, microsoft-azure

When googling "Ethereum indexer," Google seems to only return a usenet indexer page on Reddit and something related to Microsoft Azure. For that reason, I'm asking here: What are some good indexers for Ethereum, and possible alternatives for EthereumJ? Bonus points if they're opensource.

Comment: Whats an "indexer"?

Comment: An indexer is software that keeps track of the blockchain and puts it into a database. It keeps the database up-to-date, handles reorganizations, and thus allows developers to build applications that can reference the latest state of the blockchain with ease.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use your own node / client?

Comment: If [this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/269/87) does not answer your question, it's for me unclear what you are asking. You can still edit your post and clarify what you exactly want to do. What does EthereumJ what other clients don't?