# What are the two arguments to a RETURN opcode?

Tags: evm, opcode

The `RETURN` opcode in the EVM takes 2 arguments(ie, consumes two elements from the stack), but what do they represent? I tried to understand the yellow paper describing them, but I don't understand the notation used.

For reference this is the section in the yellow paper:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The 2 arguments to the `RETURN` opcode are a **starting offset and length** specifying a segment of memory.

The EVM execution is stopped and data consisting of the memory bytes from [start, start+len-1] are the output of the execution.

Example:

If memory is [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], a return with starting offset=1 and length=4 would produce a result (output) of 4 bytes (6, 7, 8, 9).

Comment: Memory as in the "storage" mechanism, or as in treating the stack like a flat array of memory?

Comment: Memory as what is stored by the `MSTORE` opcode.

Comment: By chance do you know of a "plain text" reference for all the opcode arguments? Other than the yellow paper's mathy notation, I can't find any actual reference beyond the code itself (which isn't always too clear)

Comment: Regarding EVM code, since there's [implementations across a number of languages](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/269/what-exactly-is-an-ethereum-client-and-what-clients-are-there) that may help reason about them.  I don't know of a simpler reference and IMHO a new, clearer reference is more than welcome but it should still be complete.

Comment: You may find our implementation is fairly readable reference for opcodes (though I would like increase the number of comments there): https://github.com/eris-ltd/eris-db/blob/develop/manager/eris-mint/evm/vm.go#L187. @Ethan has a nice low-level guide, though not completely comprehensive as a spec https://github.com/ebuchman/evm-tools/blob/master/analysis/guide.md. I too would like to see the Ethereum spec presented in a more appropriate format than the yellow paper...

Comment: The two arguments of `RETURN` are not start and end of the return data, but start and length.

Comment: @gernot Yikes, really try avoiding making a mistake through the years and should have been more careful on this one. Please comment if you see others answers with an error. Thanks.