# Modifying Ethereum implementation for private network

Tags: evm

I am aware of the basic functioning of the Ethereum blockchain and its Smart Contracts technology. However I would like to know if I could just download any Ethereum implementation, create my private network and create my own cryptocurrency, off the main Blockchain. I think I can do it but I read that the purpose is for development, as if I were making “fake” Ether; I actually want to make it for real implementation, but with another name.

Also with that implementation, I would like to be able to programmatically create my own Contracts inside my new Blockchain, so just like Ethereum works right now but with private, independent access and not linked in any way to the current implementation.

Do I have to do how some tutorials point out (https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0) or is that just for debugging and there is another way? And in case I have to download Geth or any of the sort, which one would be recommended? I already know Python and I would not like to be forced to learn Go if I can use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I would like to know if I could just download any Ethereum
>   implementation, create my private network and create my own
>   cryptocurrency, off the main Blockchain.

Yes, you're free to do this.

> I think I can do it but I read that the purpose is for development, as
>   if I were making “fake” Ether; I actually want to make it for real
>   implementation, but with another name.

You're free to do this, too.

> ...or is that just for debugging and there is another way?

That link show you one way to do it. There will be countless other ways, depending on how different or similar you want your chain to be.

> And in case I have to download Geth or any of the sort, which one
>   would be recommended?

Geth and Parity are the [most popular](https://www.ethernodes.org/), but there are other clients. You're free to choose one based on your language preference.

See: [What exactly is an Ethereum client and what clients are there?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/269/what-exactly-is-an-ethereum-client-and-what-clients-are-there)

> I already know Python and I would not like to be forced to learn Go if
>   I can use them interchangeably.

Maybe have a look at [Pyethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum).

Comment: Thank you! Is there some kind of tutorial where u can learn how the code was written, how the protocol exactly works so to modify it and make my own version? I checked GitHub and I find it impossible to just ahead and read through all the code to understand it.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't anything like that, and a lot of the client code isn't commented very well, either. To understand how the protocol works you'll either need to read the code or read the Yellow Paper. There are lots of articles that explain things from a high level, but they're too general to be useful when writing your own client. I'd recommend reading through the pages on the wiki to begin with. There are code snippets here and there which may help: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki