# Geth-Maximum peer count?

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I am wondering what does "Maximum peer count ETH=25 LES=0 total=25" What is this eth=25 ? Les = 0 ?"mean and why shoud we have maximum peer count. When we say peer count does it mean people who are involved in the chain sharing with my pc?

Answer (score 1):

> When we say peer count does it mean people who are involved in the chain sharing with my pc?

That's correct. So...

> What is this eth=25 ?

That's the number of peers running normal, non-light clients.

> Les = 0 ?

The number running [light](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol) clients.

Of interest:

- [What exactly is an Ethereum client and what clients are there?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/269/what-exactly-is-an-ethereum-client-and-what-clients-are-there?rq=1)
- [What is Geth's "light" sync, and why is it so fast?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/what-is-geths-light-sync-and-why-is-it-so-fast)