# Why is Ethereum licensed under the LGPLv3 license?

Tags: go-ethereum, clients, besu, trinity

Simple question, which I cannot answer myself.
Why Ethereum have an LGPLv3 license?
Bitcoin has MIT license.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Until client teams answer for themselves, here is information on non-GPL clients.

From [What exactly is an Ethereum client and what clients are there?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/269/what-exactly-is-an-ethereum-client-and-what-clients-are-there) there's two of them:

[Besu](https://github.com/hyperledger/besu) (Java) is Apache 2.

[Trinity](https://github.com/ethereum/trinity) (Python) is MIT.

Comment: IMHO all derivatives of Ethereum (with LGPLv3) should hold the same license.

Comment: Which is not the case of Besu and Trinity - regards to dates on GitHub repository and codebase.
Latest commits on following links:
https://github.com/hyperledger/besu/commits/master?after=310e0b77e5f750159ca7c8fe85a4658e0c05e2a9+2100
https://github.com/ethereum/trinity/commits/master?after=34cd38efceacbc8ffa490e808939af16957a4d5f+6170

Comment: I open this topic on the Trinity project and get a straight answer from a team member of Ethereum. You can change the license from LGPLv3 to MIT. More info: https://github.com/ethereum/trinity/issues/1734

I will keep this question still open to get opinion from legal point of view.

Comment: You have it backwards.  Correct is "MIT licensed software can be re-licensed as GPL software, and integrated with other GPL software, but not the other way around."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License

Comment: I agree that: "MIT licensed software can be re-licensed as GPL..." But as mentioned before this discussion is vice-versa. Trinity migrates from LGPLv3 to MIT. And they announce it publicly in the issue I sent.

Comment: Trinity was always MIT: it did *not* migrate from LGPLv3 to MIT (because that migration is not possible).  In the [1734 issue you linked](https://github.com/ethereum/trinity/issues/1734), it is **wrong** to "assume any fork of Ethereum (licensed under LGPLv3) can hold MIT license".

Comment: Well, it seems like different people have different opinions. And your assumption is in contrast with the following discussion: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9739/can-i-change-the-license-of-a-forked-project-from-lgplv3-to-mit/9741#9741
The answer in the following link was "No" and you are saying basically "Yes". But for sure Trinity wasn't written from scratch - it is derivation work.
Please look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design also. I am really curious why you can be so sure.

Comment: What makes you say Trinity wasn't a clean room design?  You can double-check with them at github.com/ethereum/trinity/issues if you'd like.

Comment: Sir, I am not the only one who is saying that. I am saying, Trinity needs strong legal opinion regards to the license. For sure it is derivative work. I want to be sure that users of Trinity and Bisu will not have issues.